# Does a stationary bike need a power meter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A power meter is a strain gauge that can be attached to a bike to give real time power data. Often stationary trainers will have power meters. But I got to wondering: Does a stationary bike need a separate device to directly measure power?

If the manufacturer knows the weight of the flywheel and other components, the friction of the system, and the length of the crank arms (maybe there is other info you need), can't they just calculate power from rpms of the wheel? In real life a direct measurement with strain gauge makes sense because there are so many external factors like wind, road conditions, traffic, etc.

My determination, based on a similar problem, is that you do not need a specific device to directly measure power. Imagine you have a 100 lb block on a rope. The coefficient of friction of the floor is known. The block has a speedometer on it. Couldn't you create a simple program to:

1. Measure the average speed from point $a$ to point $b$.
2. Divide by time to get the average acceleration.
3. Use $F = ma$ to get the average force.
4. Multiply force $\times$ velocity.
5. Get the power over the time step.

If this is valid, would it translate to the more complex system of the stationary bike?

Answer (score 0):

No, a stationary bike does not need a power meter based on a strain gauge.  My stationary bike reads out a power measurement based on exactly the kind of setup you describe; it measures the rate at which the wheel is turning and checks the friction setting, then outputs an approximate value for how much power I am exerting by pedaling.

The setup is not very precise, for a couple reasons.  There is discretization noise in the measurement of the wheel rpm, which makes the output increase in jumps, rather than continuously, as I pedal faster.  I also don't know how accurate the friction measurement was when the bike was knew, but over time the friction applied has definitely decreased some, as the friction-applying elements have worn down.  Still, I find it roughly accurate enough to gauge the kind of workout I am getting.

Comment: In addition, the resistance of a static trainer varies quite a large amount with temperature, meaning that often the power reading from a cheap trainer is not consistent within the same session

Comment: @Buzz So do you think over time a separate power meter would be more accurate?

Comment: @RyanC A separate strain gauge power meter would certainly have the potential to be more accurate, but that would depend on exactly how it was implemented.  I would not automatically assume that the strain gauge would be better.